# Take Sample Between Method

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am getting this error:

> The type arguments for method 'Extensions.Extensions.Between(string, string, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
    public static string Between<T>(this string Source, string First, string Second)
    {
        return Source.Split(new string[] { First }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split(new string[] { Second }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0].Trim();
    }

string c = "abcd".Between("b", "d");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a generic type `T` which isn't being used, hence the compiler cant infer which type it is. You can remove it from your method:

```
public static string Between(this string Source, string First, string Second)
{
    return Source.Split(new string[] { First }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split(new string[] { Second }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0].Trim();
}
```

Comment: yes you are right, thank you. I'll accept answer in 11 minutes :)